# Error `object required` while trying to run MS Access queries in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to run Access DB queries in Excel, but facing problem.

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database 

Set dbs = CurrentDb
dbs.Execute "DELETE FROM tblMyTable WHERE Bad", dbFailOnError
```

here it's getting

> run time error 424 object required

exactly on the 2ndline

```
set dbs = CurrentDb
```

I already added reference DAO 3.6 object library. what to keep in place of `CurrentDB`. My MsAccess DB is in local disk.

Comment: You need to do something like `Set dbs = OpenDatabase("C:\db1.mdb")`

Comment: Hi Xidgel,Thanks for the quick response. but what if my DB is already Opened?

Comment: I used this code before declaring dbs variable                                                                                                    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\" & sUser & "\Downloads\ICO\" & DB & ".mdb"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CurrentDb` isn't recognized by Excel, so it's being treated as an empty variant, since you haven't assigned it anything. Using `Option Explicit` will prevent this sort of problem in the future.

If your DB is already open, try something like: `Set dbs = GetObject(,"Access.Application").CurrentDb`

```
Option Explicit '### This goes at the VERY TOP of ALL MODULES
Sub foo()

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database 
    Dim appAccess as Object '# Access.Application
    Set appAccess = GetObject(,"Access.Application") '# Get a handle on Access 
    Set dbs = appAccess.CurrentDb
    dbs.Execute "DELETE FROM tblMyTable WHERE Bad", dbFailOnError

End Sub
```